# Keytool batch file closing automatically

Tags: batch-file

I have a very simple batch file that doesn't seem to want to stay open... I've tried PAUSE, cmd /k and even timeouts.

the Code:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin
keytool -exportcert -alias logistic -keystore "M:\0Desktop\Apps\zTo Be Sorted\MagazineKeystoreFiles\BSM.keystore.file" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
PAUSE
```

Any thoughts? What am I missing? If I run multiple timeout commands it will work until it reaches the second code line (keytool line). If I run these commands in a cmd prompt it stays open as it should.

Comment: is `keytool` a batch file? If so, use `call keytool...`

Comment: Is keytool a batch file?  If so you need to use the CALL command. `CALL Keytoool ......`

Comment: adding call doesn't work unfortunately. Keytool is a java key and certificate management utility.

Comment: Does the keytool command execute and provide the output you need?  Run your batch file from a cmd prompt instead of executing with your mouse.  What is the name of your batch file?

Comment: IF you are looking to get output logged, you can do that by messing with various combinations of carets "<<", "<", etc. You can google the proper format for them with the rest of the command params needed.

Comment: OP, unfortunatly some salty people deleted some valuable info.Just verify you got line 2 100% how it's supposed to, sounds like thats where ur code is breaking

Comment: @Squashman it's too quick to tell if it provides the output or not via batch file but when run directly from the command prompt, yes, it works as it should. The name of the batch file is "Key generation - BSM.bat"

Comment: @4g0tt3nSou1 the code works just as it should if i run it within the command prompt, outside of the batch file.

Comment: I am not saying to run the commands from the command prompt. I am telling you to run the batch file from the cmd prompt.

Comment: @Squashman thank you, this helped with troubleshooting. Infact I needed to modify the change directory command to this:

cd /d C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin

Answer (score 0):

Seems the Change directory command was the cause of the issue. Once I added "/d" the script works as it should. The batch file was saved on a different drive to where I was running keytool...

Code:

```
cd /d C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin
```